# JavaScript: write a function that returns true if there exists at least one number that is larger than array --> not a function error

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, ternary

I want to write a function that returns true if there exists at least one number that is larger than or equal to n.

Below is my code.  I am trying to use array methods and ternary operators.

```
function existsHigher(arr, n) {
  let newArr = [];

  arr.forEach(e => {
    if (n>e) {
      newArr.push(n)
    }
  })
  console.log(newArr)
  (newArr.length !== 0) ? true:false
}

existsHigher([5, 3, 15, 22, 4], 10) //➞ should return true
```

My code is returning:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Always** use semicolons unless you're *sure* you understand the rules for ASI, but even then, it's probably not a good idea. Also, you need to `return` on that last line for the expression to be returned (and the conditional operator is unnecessary, you can just use `return newArr.length > 0`)

Comment: All fine ideas, but I'm not sure any of them are what's actually wrong with the code.

Comment: yes, the ternary doesn't work even with the added semicolons

Comment: As @CertainPerformance said, you have to `return` the ternary. Just change the last line in that function to `return newArr.length > 0` (because you don't even need the ternary)

Comment: @RobertHarvey The error OP is seeing is definitely due to the lack of a semicolon just before the last line in the function, and for the desired output, OP just needs to add the `return` to the last line for the expression that follows it to be returned, otherwise the function will return `undefined` by default (and the last line there, which comes up with the output he wants, will just be an unused expression)